# Scrapy - Error Opening Archive - Failed to Open

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

I'm new to Scrapy and trying to install it on my MacBook Pro (10.9.1). The documentation that I read here http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.14/intro/install.html#download-and-install-an-official-release  indicates that I should enter this

```
tar zxf Scrapy-X.X.X.tar.gz
cd Scrapy-X.X.X
python setup.py install
```

And so after doing that, I get the following error message:

```
Error opening archive: Failed to open 'scrapy-scrapy-0.22.0-6-gfb5c9c5.tar.tar.tar'
```

I'm assuming I'm supposed to run this in the Terminal. I'm guessing that because I'm new to this, that there's something obvious I missing. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @SurfKauari12 Is there anything else you want to add? All your steps seem to be correct assuming you've used version numbers instead of `x.x.x`.

Comment: what happens when you eliminate step 1 by opening the original download archive in finder? the error seems to imply you have tar'd your unzipped file twice over

Comment: @AshokaLella - Thanks for getting back. I can't think of any other details that might be helpful, except for perhaps the install requirements http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.14/intro/install.html#requirements I installed everything except for "simplejson" since it wasn't required. Thanks!

Comment: @WarrenBurton Thanks for the suggestion. The original tarball came downloaded as scrapy-scrapy-0.23.0-15-gb14dabb.tar.gz, so first I tried pasting that name into the terminal verbatim; when that didn't work I tried alternatives like Scrapy-0.23.0-15-gb14dabb.tar.gz and scrapy-0.23.0-15-gb14dabb.tar.gz but still no luck.

Comment: use "7-Zip" tool to unzip the file